# Visual Studio 2010 hangs in MVC3 Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

It hangs on for 10 seconds in different situations, in cs files, in aspx, chtml files, when opening solution explorer and so on...

Cumputer: i7, 8Gb RAM, SSD

- Project is using SVN
- No antivirus
- No files on network resources
- Tried on 2 different MVC3 Projects

What I have tried:

1. Disabling all extensions
2. Uninstaling resharper
3. Performing Clean Install
4. Uninstalling Web Authoring Component
5. Changing Editor for ASPX/CHTML files
6. Performing "ngen /delete System.Web.Mvc" etc, "ngen update"
7. Uninstalling SP1
8. Moving project from HDD to SSD
9. Uninstalling Visual SVN
10. Removing all bin/obj directories
11. Removing .suo file
12. Reinstalling MVC3

Is there any way to analyze logs or dumps to figure out what causing hangs?

UPDATE1:
Debugging visual studio the output window shows messages like these:

```
'devenv.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'devenv.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'devenv.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'devenv.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread '<No Name>' (0xffc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x17a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x554) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x11f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

etc

Comment: Launch a second copy of VS, attach its debugger to the first copy, pause when it's frozen, and look at the stack trace.

Comment: What do you see in the Call Stack in the second copy when it's frozen?

Comment: Disable "Just my Code" in debugger options and look again.  Also, when replying, please use `@SLaks` to notify me of your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why VS hangs:
my notebook has 2 video-adapters: integrated and discrete.
NVIDIA driver allows user to choose which adapter to use for a particular application.

I have an option set to: Use discrete for all applications.

So when VS uses my discrete video adapter - hangs are back.